# How to use delimiter having multiple characters using apache commons csv

Tags: java, apache, csv

I have a input file whose delimiter is a combination of characters like #$#. But apache commons CSVParser consider only a character not multiple characters. Please find the input file:

```
Rajeev Kumar Singh ♥#$#rajeevs@example.com#$#+91-9999999999#$#India
Sachin Tendulkar#$#sachin@example.com#$#+91-9999999998#$#India
Barak Obama#$#barak.obama@example.com#$#+1-1111111111#$#United States
Donald Trump#$#donald.trump@example.com#$#+1-2222222222#$#United States
```

Code snippet:

```html
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class CSVReader {
    private static final String SAMPLE_CSV_FILE_PATH = "./users.csv";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try (

                Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(SAMPLE_CSV_FILE_PATH));
                CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader,  CSVFormat.EXCEL.withDelimiter('#'))
        ) {
            long recordCount;
            List<CSVRecord> csvRecords = csvParser.getRecords();
        }
    }

}
```

Please help me in using delimiter with multiple characters in above example, delimiter is only a single character which is '#'. I need to set the delimiter as '#$#'.

Comment: You could implement a `Reader` class that replaces `#$#` with, say, just `#` or `;`. So you wrap the file reader and pass your custom reader to the `CSVParser`. Alternatively: `sed -i 's/#\$#/;/g <your-file>` will replace `#$#` with `;`.

Comment: I tried to replace in reader class but I couldnt.

Comment: Why don't you post the code that you tried then? What I described should work, so you might have done it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class ReplacingReader extends BufferedReader {

    private final  Function<String, String> replacer;

    public ReplacingReader(Reader in, Function<String, String> replacer) {
        super(in);
        this.replacer = replacer;
    }

    @Override
    public String readLine() throws IOException {
        return replacer.apply(super.readLine());
    }
}

            Reader reader = new ReplacingReader(
                    Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(SAMPLE_CSV_FILE_PATH)),
                    line -> line.replace("#$#", "§")
                );
            CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader,  CSVFormat.EXCEL.withDelimiter('§'))
```

The buffering now is done twice, one could use other Reader/FileInputStream and such.

Comment: Thanks all for your support. Finally I made it with below method

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite clear why use `CSVParser` in your case. I just tested it locally with your data and come up with this parsing demo:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("csv.txt").toURI()))) {
        lines.forEach(line -> {
            String[] words = line.split("#\\$#");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
        });
    } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException ignored) {
        ignored.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
[Rajeev Kumar Singh ♥, rajeevs@example.com, +91-9999999999, India]
[Sachin Tendulkar, sachin@example.com, +91-9999999998, India]
[Barak Obama, barak.obama@example.com, +1-1111111111, United States]
[Donald Trump, donald.trump@example.com, +1-2222222222, United States]
```

By the way, the **csv.txt** is in the `resources`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 public List<CSVRecord> getCSVRecords(String path, String delimiter) throws IOException {
        List<CSVRecord> csvRecords = null;
        Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(path));
        List<String> replaced = lines.map(line -> line.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(delimiter), "§")).collect(Collectors.toList());
        try (
                BufferedReader buffer =
                        new BufferedReader(new StringReader(String.join("\n", replaced)));
                CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(buffer, CSVFormat.EXCEL.withDelimiter('§'))
        ) {
            csvRecords = csvParser.getRecords();
            return csvRecords;
        }
    }
```